# How to Multiple Arrays (+formation) using PHP and Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom

I found my way around web scraping and i'm trying to figure out he proper way to get data from the buffer that is filled with the page.

- i'm including my variables, that have timezone and simple html dom in
  it
- i get the img's and the titles from searching the dom, but can't seem
  to find a way to have multiple queries with the foreach, i know i'm
  missing on knowledge here, but i've hit bottom on searching and
  reading.
- i get variables from a previous form using get thats why i have the
  query string on the top.

what i need is :

- to **fetch the data in an array**
- to be able to use them inside a table and such. 
  (image on the *left* wrapped text on the *right* and some other data.)

**thank you in advance, help is going to be greatly appreciated.**

```
<?php
// includes and variables
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/variables.php");                             // all includes
// decleratus
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/file.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];                  // url+selected from prev
// shd stuff
$html = new simple_html_dom();                                                              // Load shd
$html->load_file($url);                                                                     // Load a file
// 1st array
foreach ($html->find("div.row img") as $varImgStr) 
{           
    $varImg = '<p style="margin-left:25px">' . $varImgStr. '</p>';
    echo $varImg ;
}
// 2nd array
foreach ($html->find("div.row span strong") as $varTitleStr) 
{           
    $varTitle = '<p style="margin-left:25px">' . $varTitleStr. '</p>';
    echo $varTitle ;
}
// does echo full $html output
//echo $html;                                                                               
// clear mem
$html->clear();                                                                             
?>
```

I'm deploying on my workplace an off-line (no internet needed) app using Php Desktop.

What i'm using :

- [PHP Desktop](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/)

  - portable apache with php-cli and sqlite features, setting don't allow resizing and maximizing, only minimizing and other [goodies](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/wiki/Settings)
- BAT scripts

  - [bat2exe](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) and the script fetches the main executable and settings file from a server on the network, result is always validated files and data (included temporary wget/unzip/rm [unix binaries for windows](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/))
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) and others for the Navigation
- [Right click disabler](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noright.htm), plus left click enabled only for single click on images and/or links and [no selection](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noselect.htm).
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with may [plugins](http://npp-plugins.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a multidimensional array:

```
foreach ($html->find("div.row img") as $varImgStr) 
{           
    $mainArray['varImg'][] = '<p style="margin-left:25px">' . $varImgStr. '</p>';
}

foreach ($html->find("div.row span strong") as $varTitleStr) 
{           
    $mainArray['varTitleStr'][] = '<p style="margin-left:25px">' . $varTitleStr. '</p>';
}
```

This creates an array with two elements - ['varImg'] and ['varTitleStr']. Each of those elements is an array containing all of the images or titles found. You can print_r($mainArray); to see the structure. Note that this approach depends on finding the same number of images and titles in the same order.

```
//To print the array in a simple table

echo '<table><thead>
    <th>Image</th><th>Title</th>
    </thead><tbody>';

for ($i=0; $i<count($mainArray['varImg']); $i++) {
     echo '<tr> <td>' . $mainArray['varImg'][$i] . '</td> 
           <td>' . $mainArray['varTitleStr'][$i] . '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Note that in the for loop, the count is taken from $mainArray['varImg'], not from $mainArray. You can read more about multidimensional arrays [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-95).